# why the subthread can not see the changed static variable ? JMM or volatile

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, volatile

Here is an example of the usage of `volatile` keyword.

```
public class Test3{
    public static volatile boolean stop = false;// if volatile is not set, the loop will not stop
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                int i=0;
                while(!stop){
                    i++;
                    // add this line
//                  System.out.println(i);
                    // or this block
//                  try {
//                      Thread.sleep(1);
//                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                      e.printStackTrace();
//                  }
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        stop = true;
    }
}
```

It's easy to understand that if `volatile` is set, JVM should load the updated value from memory while checking its value, then the while loop can stop as expected. But question is, should not the static variable change at the same time? There may be some delay but eventually, this change should be detected. no? I've tested that if we add some print code or sleep code, this change can be detected? Can someone teach me why it likes that? Maybe it's about the JMM.

Comment: see here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/

Comment: "should not the static variable change at the same time" - what do you mean? At the same time of what? Of assignment to the "stop" variable? Indeed the "stop" variable should change,  why do you ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time, in the sense of wall-clock time, has no meaning for the memory visibility. What matters is the *synchronization order* between synchronization actions. Reading and writing a non-`volatile` field is not a synchronization action, so in the absence of any other synchronization action, there is no ordering between them.

So even if the main thread completed a year ago, so the write must have been done from the main thread’s perspective, the subthread may continue to run, running forever; the write has not happened from its perspective. It also doesn’t know that the main thread has terminated. Note that performing an action capable of detecting that the other thread has terminated, is a synchronization action that may establish an order.

But since the actual program behavior also depends on the JIT compiler and optimizer, some code changes may have an impact, even if it is not guaranteed.

E.g. inserting `sleep` does not imply any memory visibility:

[JLS §17.3. Sleep and Yield](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3):

> It is important to note that neither `Thread.sleep` nor `Thread.yield` have any synchronization semantics. In particular, the compiler does not have to flush writes cached in registers out to shared memory before a call to `Thread.sleep` or `Thread.yield`, nor does the compiler have to reload values cached in registers after a call to `Thread.sleep` or `Thread.yield`.

But it may stop the optimizer from considering the loop to be a hotspot that needs optimizations.

When you insert a `System.out.println` statement, the internal synchronization of the `PrintStream` may have an impact on the overall memory visibility, though this effect also isn’t guaranteed, as the main thread does not synchronize on that `PrintStream`.

By the way there isn’t even a guaranty that preemptive thread switching ever happens between threads of the same priority. Hence, it would be a valid execution, if a JVM tries to complete your subthread after `start()` has been called, before giving the CPU back to the main thread.

In that execution scenario, with no `sleep` in the loop, the subthread would never give up the CPU, so `stop` would never be set to `true`, even if declared `volatile`. That would be another reason to avoid polling loops, though there might be no real life execution environment without preemptive thread switching anymore. Most of today’s execution environments even have multiple CPUs so not giving up a CPU won’t prevent other threads from executing.

Still, to be formally correct, you should enforce an ordering between a write to the `stop` variable and the reading of the variable, like declaring the variable `volatile` and insert an action that may cause the thread to release the CPU eventually, when `quit` is still `false`.

Answer (score 2):

> It's easy to understand that if volatile is set, JVM should load the
>   updated value from memory while checking its value, then the while
>   loop can stop as expected.

[`volatile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) is some kind of `rule` or `mechanism`, not about concrete implemention above. It is used to build [`happends-before`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) relationship between threads:

> Using volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency
>   errors, because any write to a volatile variable establishes a
>   happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same
>   variable. **This means that changes to a volatile variable are always
>   visible to other threads. What's more, it also means that when a
>   thread reads a volatile variable, it sees not just the latest change
>   to the volatile, but also the side effects of the code that led up the
>   change**.

---

Without `volatile` or other synchronization, the update to static variable **could** be seen to other threads with some delay, and **could not** be seen forever because [memory barriar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier). **It is uncertain**. Even you add some print code or sleep code, and find it works, it does not mean it can still work in other enviroment or other moment.

---

However, if you add the print code in both the `while loop` and the `main` thread:

```
while(!stop){
    i++;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

and

```
stop = true;
System.out.println("some");
```

JMM can gurantee that the `stop = true` will be detected in the loop(at least on oracle jdk 8u161), this is because `System.out.println` is [`synchronized`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html), which also can build a `happens-before` relationship between involved threads, see the source code:

```
public void println(String x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: The JMM only guarantees it, as long as the `PrintStream` implementation internally uses `synchronized` in this way, which is not guaranteed in its API documentation. As long as it does, we get the guaranty to never see more than one number printed after `"some"`, as the subthread should perceive the changed `stop` after the first subsequent print operation. That’s the best we can get in an environment that doesn’t specify any timing or thread scheduling behavior for equal priority threads…

Comment: You got it. I do not think use `System.out.print` is a good idea either.